# WSO2 ESB : Issues while creating DB2 Datasource

Tags: db2, wso2, wso2-esb

I was trying to create a new datasource for wso2 esb ( happens to be DB2). I copied the `db2jcc.jar` and `db2jcc_license_cu.jar` file to `<ESB_HOME>/repository/components/dropins` and `<ESB_HOME>/repository/components/lib` folders.

Now I am trying to connect to DB2 database. I filled out the information necessary for establishing the connection but I am getting the following error.

```
Error establishing data source connection: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

This is how I am configuring the database :

```
Data Source Provider : Default
Driver : com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
URL : jdbc:db2://HOSTNAME:50000/DB
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Few possibilities: one or more of the URL parameters (DB2 server hostname, service port, or database name) is incorrect; the DB2 instance is not running; the firewall between your application and the DB2 server prevents communications on the selected port.

Comment: We found the problem. Shouldn't have copied db2jcc.jar files into <ESB_HOME>/repository/components/dropins folder. Removing the jar files from that folder solved the problem.

Comment: Though it does not make much sense, I'm glad your problem is resolved.